# Using popen() with minicom in C gives me garbage values

Tags: c, arduino, popen, raspberry-pi

I am making a script to get the values sent by arduino on serial (serial.write) on a raspberry pi (debian wheezy) through USB serial. The values are sent by a proximity capacitive sensor (capsense library). When I open a terminal window with this command

```
minicom -b 9600 -o -D /dev/ttyACM0
```

I get (almost) what i want, lines of characters that respond to the proximity of my hand ; so the sending part is working great, and the receiving by raspberry too.
So i used popen() in my C code to get these values by blocks of 4 (because there's 2 sensor values, space-separated), but when i execute the program i get only garbage values that doesn't seem to respond in any way to the proximity of my hand.
Moreover when i start the program i can't stop it, by using ctrl+c or ctrl+z.

Here's my C program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {

    // open a stream with popen with the (working) command    
    FILE *stream = popen("minicom -b 9600 -o -D /dev/ttyACM0", "r");

    while (!feof(stream) && !ferror(stream)) {

        // declare a buffer, read the stream
        char buf[4];
        int bytesRead = fread(buf, 1, 4, stream);

        // print stuff to see what has been read
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); i++) {
            printf("%i", (int)buf[i]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    pclose(stream);
    return 0;
}
```

and here's the program on my arduino :

```
#include <CapacitiveSensor.h>

// sensors
CapacitiveSensor vibeCS = CapacitiveSensor(4,2);
CapacitiveSensor gongCS = CapacitiveSensor(8,7);

// note values
long vibe;
long gong;

void setup() {

  // pin modes
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13, INPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

    vibe = vibeCS.capacitiveSensor(150);
    gong = gongCS.capacitiveSensor(150);

    // communication
    Serial.write(vibe);
    Serial.write(' ');
    Serial.write(gong);
    Serial.write('\n');

    delay(10);
}
```

Any idea why this is happening ?

I've also been working on another way of seeing the problem as follows :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "rs232.h"

#define COMPORT         0x0000      // see explanation below
#define BAUDRATE        9600
#define RECEIVE_CHARS   4

int main (void) {

    // declare a buffer
    unsigned char receive_buffer[RECEIVE_CHARS];

    // open the serial communication
    RS232_OpenComport(COMPORT, BAUDRATE);

    while(1) {

        // poll data from arduino
        RS232_PollComport(COMPORT, receive_buffer, RECEIVE_CHARS);

        // print stuff 
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < sizeof(receive_buffer); i++) {
            printf("%i", (int)receive_buffer[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

   RS232_CloseComport(COMPORT);
   return 0;
}
```

In the way of doing, i've used 0x0000 as comport but i don't think this is the right one. I've set it this way because

```
setserial -g /dev/ttyACM0
```

gives me

```
/dev/ttyACM0, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0, Flags: low_latency
```

so if this gives me nice looking data in the terminal, it gives only 0000 even though i get my hand close to the sensor, so it doesn't seem to receive the data.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
vibeCS.capacitiveSensor(  )
```

returns a long (4 bytes) not an int (2 bytes). However it must be over loaded b/c it lets you compile.

http://playground.arduino.cc//Main/CapacitiveSensor?from=Main.CapSense

2
you might have to check your processor to see if it is big ended or little ended.

Edit :
I suspect the code below does not do what you want it to do.

```
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(receive_buffer); i++) {
         i = 
         printf("%i", (int)receive_buffer[i]);
    }
```

For example lets say there is one int in the buff. The int has a value of 4242;
the value of 4242 in hex is [00 00 10 92]

so 
buf[0] = 0x92 = 147 ,

buf[1] = 0x10 = 16 ,

buf[2] = 0x0 = 0,

buf[3] = 0x0 = 0;

So your code would print 1471600 for the value that is 4242. the code below show what I am talking about.

```
1 #include <stdio.h>
2 #include <stdlib.h>
3 
4 int main()
5 {
6         unsigned char buf[4];
7         unsigned int *fill = buf;
8         *fill = 4242;
9 
10         int i;
11         for(i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); i++) {
12             printf("%i", (unsigned int)buf[i]);
13         }
14 
15 }

printed value is [1461600]
```

now for something useful. The code below might fix all your problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {

    // open a stream with popen with the (working) command    
    FILE *stream = popen("minicom -b 9600 -o -D /dev/ttyACM0", "r");

    while (!feof(stream) && !ferror(stream)) {

        // declare a buffer, read the stream
        char buf[4];
        int bytesRead = fread(buf, 1, 4, stream);

        // print stuff to see what has been read
        int *i = buf;
        printf("%i", *i);
        //for(i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); i++) {
        //   printf("%i", (int)buf[i]);
        //}

        printf("\n");
    }

    pclose(stream);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've changed the arduino's code, replaced int by long for correctness but it does not affect my problem. The raspberry's ARM processor is little endian.